# Setting the private data within main function

Tags: c++, c++14, private, public

I tried updating the private data in the main function. It worked fine for one private variable. But working differently for more than one variable.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    private:
    char data;
    int f;
    public:
    A(){
        data = 'a';
        f = 0;
    }
    char getdata(){
        return data;
    }
    int getf(){
        return f;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A k;
    char *p = (char*)&k;
    *p = '0';
    int* j = (int*)&k;
    *j = 100;
    cout<< k.getdata()<<endl;
    cout<<k.getf();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect output of `0\n100`. But it gives `d\n0`.

Comment: Is it not UB to do this? You're assuming the memory layout of a C++ class.

Comment: Why you are making your life hard? Just provide accessors (getters setters - best solution) and/or provide respective constructors with parameters, xor just make everything public.

Comment: Why do you believe `&k` is the location of both members? (As a side note, this is thoroughly undefined and you can't expect anything in particular from it.)

Comment: Marek R I know about it bro! But I wanted to change from the main function and thats the main objective of question..

Answer (score -1):

As I am Using the same address for both I am unable to change. So, I added size of char to the referral address k i.e., &(k)+sizeof(char) I got my answer by this step.

Comment: This only "worked" because there is more than one error in this code,and they just happened to cancel each other out.